# How to reinstall broken pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have been trying create virtual environment for Django blog application. When I try create virtual environment I am getting following error:

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 venv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3019, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3003, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3032, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 646, in _build_master
    ws = cls()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 639, in __init__
    self.add_entry(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 695, in add_entry
    for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2012, in find_on_path
    if len(os.listdir(fullpath)) == 0:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyYAML-3.12.dist-info'
```

When I try test `pip3` basic functionality by executing `pip3 install Django`, I'm getting error:

```
$ pip3 install Django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.cachecontrol'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    vendored("cachecontrol")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/wrapper.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 32, in vendored
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 47, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import dsa, rsa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.interfaces import RSABackend
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3019, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3003, in _call_aside
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3032, in _initialize_master_working_set
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 646, in _build_master
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 639, in __init__
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 695, in add_entry
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2012, in find_on_path
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyYAML-3.12.dist-info'
```

`pip` from Python 2.x works without problems. Can anyone help me? How can I reinstall broken `pip3`?

Comment: You can follow the [installation instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) to run `get-pip.py`. However, if you're using a Python package from your distro, you probably want to instead uninstall and reinstall the distro's `pip` package instead.

Comment: I ***genuinely*** doubt that pip3 is broken here.  It's likely asking you to escalate your privilege to execute the command, but doing that for a virtual environment likely defeats the purpose...

Comment: messing with distro pip considered harmful.

Comment: Meanwhile, the problem seems to be that you've been mixing and matching `pip` and `sudo pip` inappropriately, so now, plain `pip` won't work because it doesn't have write access to the directories it needs.

Comment: @abarnert How can I recovery these privileges to plain pip?

Comment: I had to change chmod of /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on Python 3.  Use the vendored `venv` to create a virtual environment:

```
python3 -m venv venv --prompt="myvenv"
```

Activate it:

```
source ./venv/bin/activate
```

Then just use `pip`, you don't need `pip3`:

```
pip install Django
```