# pip3 command is failing

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip

I did `pip3 install jira` and now every pip3 command is failing with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.cachecontrol'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.exceptions import InstallationError, CommandError, PipError
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    vendored("cachecontrol")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/wrapper.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/utils.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/certs.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/certifi/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .core import contents, where
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/certifi/core.py", line 85, in <module>
    Resource = Union[str, "os.PathLike"]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 552, in __getitem__
    dict(self.__dict__), parameters, _root=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in __new__
    for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in <genexpr>
    for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 190, in __subclasscheck__
    self._eval_type(globalns, localns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 177, in _eval_type
    eval(self.__forward_code__, globalns, localns),
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'PathLike'
```

Even `pip3 --version` is not working to paste pip3 version here.

I'm using Python3.5 (I know it's old, but I can't upgrade) in Ubuntu inside WSL. How to solve this issue?

**EDIT:** I manually uninstalled `jira` and `typing-extensions`:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jira
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jira-3.5.2.dist-info/
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/typing_extensions-4.8.0.dist-info/
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/typing_extensions.py
```

But the issue still persists.

Comment: Did you read this: [How to reinstall broken pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182155/how-to-reinstall-broken-pip)

Comment: @Luuk I saw it now. I didn't completely understood the solution given there. But `python3 -m pip --version` still gives same error as above.

Comment: @Luuk `sudo pip3 --version` is also giving the same error.

Comment: "*I did `pip3 install …` and now every pip3 command is failing…*" That explains why you should never use `sudo pip` and why using Python virtual environments is so important!

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871131/7976758

Comment: @phd I tried get-pip. Now pip (for Python2) started failing. Finally ended up `rm -rf /usr/local/bin` and `sudo apt-get install python3-pip python-pip`.